# Chart creation in ADO - No of Stories based on parent names

Tags: charts, ado

I want to create a chart in ADO board to show the number of User stories based on the parent names(Features).

How can I create this chart?

Now I have a query to list the User Stories. When I see it in chart, I am unable to choose an option to show by Feature names